# Maya crashes when duplicate special

Tags: crash, maya

I try to make instance copies of my character using Duplicate Special. But unfortunately it crashes every time I try.

For this I select my character's group "rig_group", then go to Edit → Duplicate Special ⊡

And I want to use these settings:

[image: duplicate special options]

And it crashes Maya when I hit "Apply" or "Duplicate Special".

Note that it works on this character on a fresh file.

- Test file - [M01_WalkNeutral.0080.mb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cBfuC7LaX_DhSKMHi8cmZZNMsxlVXrky/view)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that duplicate special doesn't work properly on rig's. You can use duplicate special for polygons, curves or etc.
Ps. If you wanted to duplicate special a high-poly mesh I would say that to reduce the vertex then run that but about rig_group I'm not sure.
I hope to help that to you.